# Performing date time arithmetic in custom date time class

Tags: c++, boost

I have a very naive struct representing date time which I would like to perform arithmetic on:

```
struct MyDateTime
{
    MyDateTime(int year, int month, int day, uint64_t nanos);

    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
    uint64_t nanosSinceMidnight;
};
```

I'd like to be able to add/subtract `MyDateTime` from another `MyDateTime`.

My idea was to make my struct a wrapper and use Boost internally.

I looked at Boost Posix Time:

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/date_time/examples.html#date_time.examples.time_math

But this seems to only be doing time math (not accounting for the date component).

I looked at Boost Gregorian Date but I couldn't see any time argument in the constructors.

What is the simplest way to use Boost, so I can perform datetime arithmetic?

Comment: What about this other class? `boost::locale::date_time` https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/locale/doc/html/classboost_1_1locale_1_1date__time.html#details

Comment: @rturrado I am a bit concerned about the "locale" part. Will it start looking at my OS timezone/env settings and do things i'm not expecting? I am only using UTC datetimes.

Comment: You may be right, yes. What about then using `ptime` (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html#ptime_operators) and then converting to UTC (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/date_time/examples.html#date_time.examples.local_utc_conversion)?

Comment: Yeah. Use use `boost::posix_time::ptime` and the difference type (time_duration IIRC)

Comment: @sehe But time_duration doesn't contain a date. I'm looking for datetime3 = datetime1 + datetime2

Comment: While I can understand the semantics of subtracting datetimes to get a duration, what does adding datetimes mean?

Comment: Found some time to hopefully dispel some confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you may have realized by now, dates cannot be added.

Dates and timestamps are mathematically akin to [tensors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20tensor%20is,scalars%2C%20and%20even%20other%20tensors.), in that their difference type is in a different domain.

When you commented that `time_duration` doesn't include a date, you still had a point though.

Because the `time_duration` might be the time-domain difference type (the difference type `ptime`) but we need an analog for the date-part of `ptime`, which is `boost::gregorian::date`.

Boost Gregorian dates are basically blessed tuples of (yyyy,mm,dd).So a natural difference type would just be a *signed integral number of days*. And that's *exactly** what `boost::gregorian::date_duration` is:

```
boost::gregorian::date_duration  x = date{} - date{};
boost::posix_time::time_duration y = ptime{} - ptime{};
```

> Because that type is implemented in the Gregorian module you will get correct differences, even with special cases like leap days and other anomalies: https://www.calendar.com/blog/gregorian-calendar-facts/

So, you could in fact use that type as a difference type, just for the ymd part.

### Simplify

The good news is, you don't have to bother: `boost::posix_time::ptime` encapsulates a full `boost::gregorian::date`, hence when you get a `boost::posix_time::time_duration` from subtracting `ptime`s, you will *already* get the number of days ciphered in:

```
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>

int main() {
    auto now = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();

    auto later    = now + boost::posix_time::hours(3);
    auto tomorrow = later + boost::gregorian::days(1);
    auto ereweek  = later - boost::gregorian::weeks(1);

    std::cout << later << " is " << (later - now) << " later than " << now
              << std::endl;
    std::cout << tomorrow << " is " << (tomorrow - later) << " later than " << later
              << std::endl;
    std::cout << ereweek << " is " << (ereweek - now) << " later than " << now
              << std::endl;
}
```

Starting from the current time we add 3 hours, 1 day and then subtract a week. It prints: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e4767176618dc5d6)**:

```
2021-Mar-28 01:50:45.095670 is 03:00:00 later than 2021-Mar-27 22:50:45.095670
2021-Mar-29 01:50:45.095670 is 24:00:00 later than 2021-Mar-28 01:50:45.095670
2021-Mar-21 01:50:45.095670 is -165:00:00 later than 2021-Mar-27 22:50:45.095670
```

Note that `24h` is 1 day, and -165h is (7*24 - 3) hours ago.

There's loads of smarts in the Gregorian calendar module:

```
std::cout << date{2021, 2, 1} - date{2020, 2, 1} << std::endl; // 366
std::cout << date{2020, 2, 1} - date{2019, 2, 1} << std::endl; // 365
```

Taking into account leap days. But also knowing the varying lengths of a calendar month in context:

```
auto term = boost::gregorian::months(1);

for (date origin : {date{2021, 2, 17}, date{2021, 3, 17}}) {
    std::cout << ((origin + term) - origin) << std::endl;
};
```

Prints 28 and 31 respectively.

### Applying It To Your Type

I'd suggest keeping with the library difference type, as *clearly* you had not previously given it any thought that you needed one. By simply creating some interconversions you can have your cake and eat it too:

```
struct MyDateTime {
    MyDateTime(int year = 1970, int month = 1, int day = 1, uint64_t nanos = 0)
        : year(year),
          month(month),
          day(day),
          nanosSinceMidnight(nanos) {}

    operator ptime() const {
        return {date(year, month, day),
                microseconds(nanosSinceMidnight / 1'000)};
    }

    explicit MyDateTime(ptime const& from)
        : year(from.date().year()),
          month(from.date().month()),
          day(from.date().day()),
          nanosSinceMidnight(from.time_of_day().total_milliseconds() * 1'000) {}

  private:
    int      year;
    int      month;
    int      day;
    uint64_t nanosSinceMidnight;
};
```

> Now, I would question the usefulness of keeping your `MyDateTime` type, but I realize legacy code exists, and sometimes you require a longer time period while moving away from it.

### Nanoseconds

Nanosecond precision is not enabled by default. You need to [opt in to use that]([https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/date_time/details.html#boost-common-heading-doc-spacer:~:text=To%20use%20the%20alternate%20resolution%20(96,the%20variable%20BOOST_DATE_TIME_POSIX_TIME_STD_CONFIG%20must%20be%20defined)](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/date_time/details.html#boost-common-heading-doc-spacer:%7E:text=To%20use%20the%20alternate%20resolution%20(96,the%20variable%20BOOST_DATE_TIME_POSIX_TIME_STD_CONFIG%20must%20be%20defined)).
In the sample below I do.

Be careful that al the translation units in your project use the define, or you will cause [ODR violations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule).

### Live Demo

Adding some convenience `operator<<` as well:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d3622f272f5107b8)**

```
#define BOOST_DATE_TIME_POSIX_TIME_STD_CONFIG
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
#include <vector>

using boost::posix_time::ptime;
using boost::gregorian::date;
using boost::posix_time::nanoseconds;

struct MyDateTime {
    MyDateTime(MyDateTime const&) = default;
    MyDateTime& operator=(MyDateTime const&) = default;

    MyDateTime(int year = 1970, int month = 1, int day = 1, uint64_t nanos = 0)
        : year(year),
          month(month),
          day(day),
          nanosSinceMidnight(nanos) {}

    operator ptime() const {
        return {date(year, month, day), nanoseconds(nanosSinceMidnight)};
    }

    /*explicit*/ MyDateTime(ptime const& from)
        : year(from.date().year()),
          month(from.date().month()),
          day(from.date().day()),
          nanosSinceMidnight(from.time_of_day().total_nanoseconds()) {}

  private:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, MyDateTime const& dt) {
        auto save = os.rdstate();
        os << std::dec << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(4) << dt.year << "/"
           << std::setw(2) << dt.month << "/" << std::setw(2) << dt.day << " +"
           << dt.nanosSinceMidnight;
        os.setstate(save);
        return os;
    }

    int      year;
    int      month;
    int      day;
    uint64_t nanosSinceMidnight;
};

int main() {
    namespace g = boost::gregorian;
    namespace p = boost::posix_time;
    using p::time_duration;

    std::vector<time_duration> terms{p::seconds(30), p::hours(-168),
                                     p::minutes(-15),
                                     p::nanoseconds(60'000'000'000 * 60 * 24)};

    for (auto mydt : {MyDateTime{2021, 2, 17}, MyDateTime{2021, 3, 17}}) {
        std::cout << "---- Origin: " << mydt << "\n";
        for (time_duration term : terms) {
            mydt = ptime(mydt) + term;
            std::cout << "Result: " << mydt << "\n";
        }
    };
}
```

Prints

```
---- Origin: 2021/02/17 +0
Result: 2021/02/17 +30000000000
Result: 2021/02/10 +30000000000
Result: 2021/02/09 +85530000000000
Result: 2021/02/10 +85530000000000
---- Origin: 2021/03/17 +0
Result: 2021/03/17 +30000000000
Result: 2021/03/10 +30000000000
Result: 2021/03/09 +85530000000000
Result: 2021/03/10 +85530000000000
```